# Odoo 11 which environment should I choose

Tags: linux, windows, odoo, windows-server-2012, odoo-10

Could you please tell me what will the best way to install Odoo? Windows/ Linux? If windows what version of Windows Server should I use? Windows Server 2016 Standart/ Essentials will be fine?

Please give me any advice : (

Answer (score 0):

In my view, better should be on Linux, Ubuntu 16+. and from here you will get the more guidelines. [Guidelines](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/setup/install.html)